# excel macro for checking the duplicate entries in coloumn

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I looking for a macro which shall find the duplicate entries in the other column. 
For example, the spreadsheet I've has more than 300 entries in both column A and B and the values assorted. Now, I need to find out the duplicate entries between the columns. Like westford xxxx there in the column B or not? Please help.

Column A          Column B

WestFord xxxx    1.1/2.2 1.50 Direct Link 
Direct Link      1.1/2.3 1.55 Westford xxxx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Match(Lookup_Value, Lookup_Array, [Match_type])" function.  The function returns a number, if the value is found and "N/A" if it is not.  First check column B for each element in column A. Then check Column A for each element in Column B.

If the Match function isn't enough, since you have partial matches, you could write a user defined function that identifies whether a value exists in the array.  Below is an example of a function that checks the first characters for matching.

```
Function StartsWith(InputStr As String, InArr As Range, Optional Chars As Integer = 5) As Boolean

Dim i As Integer
Dim compStr As String
Dim foundFlag As Boolean
For i = 1 To InArr.Rows.Count
    If Len(InputStr) > Chars Then     'we check to make sure inputstr isn't longer
        compStr = Left(InputStr, Chars) 'than then the number of characters we need
    Else
        compStr = InputStr              'if it is too long, then compare the whole thing
    End If
    If compStr = Left(InArr(i, 1), Len(compStr)) Then
        foundFlag = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

StartsWith = foundFlag

End Function
```

If this code in a module in an open spreadsheet, you can use StartsWith like any other function.  If you want further automation (like deleting the cells if a duplicate is found, you can write a sub to do that also!

The internet is FULL of VBA tutorials like [this one](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html).
Try a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+tutorial)

Comment: Are the matches partial matches?  If so, you might have to use VBA and write a macro / UDF that checks that, say 80% of the string matches.  If you're looking to learn, we'll happily help you.  If you're looking for someone to write the code for you, I do some contracting work.  Send me your spreadsheet with an example and I'll give you a quote.  [link](mailto:CodeJockeycom@gmail.com)

Comment: yes, these are partial matches..  Anyways, currently, I did it manually. Shall happy to learn this in future to make my life ease.. :).. Thx..